# Sending only changing data from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this table that receive from the server: (with ajax):

```
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#MyTable tbody').append("<tr>"d
             +"<td>" +data[i].A+ "</td><td>" 
             +data[i].B
             +"</td><td><input type='text' value='"
             +data[i].C+"'/></td><td><input type='text' value='"
             + data[i].D+"'/></td>"
             + "</tr>");
        });
```

C and D are edit text, that the user can change them. after the changing by the user I want to "take" the all data from the table that have changed by lines (all the lines that have been changed, even if only C (or D) have been changed, and send it by ajax with JSON. how can I read the data to a JSON?

I start to write one but I am stuck on (in this way I am sending all the table, not the only lines that changed and I want to send the only lines that have been changed):

```
function getUserData()
{
    var newData = new Array();
    $.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'),function(key,val){
        var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text]");          
        var fileldValues = {};
        fileldValues['c'] = $(inputF[0]).val();
        fileldValues['d'] = $(inputF[1]).val();
        fileldValues['a'] = $($(this).children()[0]).text();
        fileldValues['b'] = $($(this).children()[1]).text();
        newData.push(fileldValues);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(newData);
}

function saveNewData(){

var newData = getUserData();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "save",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
    newData: newData},
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `onchange` event for your text fields. When it triggers, add a class name to that element. On your save code, select only those elements that have that class name.

Event:

```
$('#MyTable input[type=text]').on('change',function() {
     $(this).addClass('changed');
})
```

Change:

```
  var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
```

to:

```
  var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text].changed");
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding, I am trying to read on google about that.
did you mean:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textbox").change(function () {
      // Call your server side
    });
    });

can you write it pls?
or edit my code.

Comment: I still may be not understand, but I need the entire line including all columns have not changed. 
it mean if one column has changed in a row, I want to move / save the entire row. (if column C or D have not been changed, I do not want to send thier row.
At the end of the process to send all relevant lines (performed by modification even in one column, send all the information of the entire line). 
Thank you.
and one more Q: where should I write the event?

Comment: o.k. I understand some things just need to know where exactly to write the event?